# How do I extract only subset of classes from torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10?

Tags: pytorch

How do I extract only 2 or 3 classes from torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10?

Standard way of loading all 10 classes

```
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])
    trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
    trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=4, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
    testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False, download=True, transform=transform)
    testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=4, shuffle=False, num_workers=2)
```

Answer (score 4):

By inspecting the [code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/datasets/cifar.html#CIFAR10) of `CIFAR10`, you can see that the data is stored as `numpy` array and the labels are stored as a list. You can therefore subclass this and filter the two arrays adequately. An example is below:

```
class SubLoader(torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10):
    def __init__(self, *args, exclude_list=[], **kwargs):
        super(SubLoader, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if exclude_list == []:
            return

        if self.train:
            labels = np.array(self.train_labels)
            exclude = np.array(exclude_list).reshape(1, -1)
            mask = ~(labels.reshape(-1, 1) == exclude).any(axis=1)

            self.train_data = self.train_data[mask]
            self.train_labels = labels[mask].tolist()
        else:
            labels = np.array(self.test_labels)
            exclude = np.array(exclude_list).reshape(1, -1)
            mask = ~(labels.reshape(-1, 1) == exclude).any(axis=1)

            self.test_data = self.test_data[mask]
            self.test_labels = labels[mask].tolist()
```

Comment: super(SubLoader, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'root'

Comment: How are you instantiating it? Both `loader = SubLoader(root='./data', train=True, download=True)` and `loader = SubLoader('./data', train=True, download=True)` should work.

Comment: Solution provided by @Jatentaki is working for older version of torchvision. Since 0.2.2, one could simply use `self.data` and `self.targets` without case distinction